# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol' threw an exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, signalr

I am getting the following exception when running Xamarin Forms iOS app after upgrade to the latest Visual Studio Mac:

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: int System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoder.FindFirstCharacterToEncodeU…}

Code:

```
        string token = s.AccessToken().Result;

        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
          .WithUrl(serverUrl, options =>
          {
              options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(token);
              options.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.LongPolling;

          })
          //.WithAutomaticReconnect()
          //.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
          //{
          //    logging.AddDebug();
          //    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
          //
          //})
          .Build();
```

I've tried adding various NuGet packages including System.Text.Json (5.0.1) but doesn't seem to be working. Any body else facing this and any suggestions how to fix? Android app is working OK.

xamarin forms - 5.0.0.2012

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 14.14.2.5

Xamarin.Android
Version: 11.2.0.0

Visual Studio Mac 8.9 (build 1651)

Comment: Have you tried a clean build by deleting bin and obj folders? And is the vs for Mac update the only change before iOS app not working? any nuget package change or code change?

Comment: SQLitePCLRaw.core.2.0.4 needs System.Memory 4.5.3 and there is no way to downgrade it to 4.5.0 as there is no older version of SQLitePCLRaw.core.2.0.4 that had dependency below 4.5.3. Any fix possible @NicoleLu-MSFT

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and the only thing that worked for me is to install System.Memory 4.5.0 (on IOS) that specific version any other version doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Its worked for me, you save my day

Comment: I was having the problem with Visual Studio 2019 16.9.3 on Windows. This solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Would be interesting to get the root cause to this (downgrading solved the issue for me as well)

Comment: SQLitePCLRaw.core.2.0.4 needs System.Memory 4.5.3 and there is no way to downgrade it to 4.5.0 as there is no older version of SQLitePCLRaw.core.2.0.4 that had dependency below 4.5.3. Any fix possible

Comment: This solution worked for me also, adding system.memory 4.5.0 to the IOS project.

Comment: This issue has bitten me with a few different newer libraries recently, like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client (6.0.1)` and `Azure.Search.Documents (11.3.0)`. I can confirm that adding `System.Memory (4.5.0)` to my Xamarin iOS project made the exception stop throwing. It's unfortunate that this seems to be happening across a variety of popular Microsoft libs, when used with Xamarin.iOS. I don't fully understand the root issue, but I do know a `MissingMethodException` occurs when one library expects an exposed method to be available in another library, but doesn't find it.